# script for adding source image to essential graphics

Tags: javascript, composition, after-effects

I'm trying to add source image to essential graphics so I use this code which is for property and change it to use for image.

```
 app.beginUndoGroup("Add to EGP");

    function add(theLayer){

    var myComp = app.project.activeItem; //Active comp
    var selectProp = theLayer.mainSource; //SOURCE selected layer;
    var myLayer = theLayer.name; //Get layer name;
    selectProp.addToMotionGraphicsTemplateAs(myComp, myLayer); //Add property to EGP and rename;
    app.project.activeItem.motionGraphicsTemplateName = "Master Properties"; //Set template name;
    myComp.openInEssentialGraphics(); //Opens comp in essential graphics panel;

    }
    var myLayers = app.project.activeItem.selectedLayers;
    for (var i = 0; i < myLayers.length; i++){
    add(myLayers[i]);
    }

    app.endUndoGroup();
};
```

I'm trying to add source image to essential graphics so I use this code which is for property and change it to use for image but it wont work.